# for loop async in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Hi I have a for loop in my node js application which calls an async function. I want to check a value and decide whether a customer is found or not. But the loop iterates until the last element. Hence my error loop is not working. I want the loop to check the response and then iterate the next loop.

for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < customerlookupresponse.data.length; i++) {
    var customer = customerlookupresponse.data[i];
    if (customer != undefined) {
        console.log("customer.id :: " + customer.id)
        var accountlookUpData = {
            customerId: customer.id
        };
        customerAccountLookUpRequest(accountlookUpData).then(data => {
            console.log("----" + i + " -- " + data);                               
            if (data && data.status === 1) {
                resolve(data);
                return;
            }else{
                reject({
                    status: 404,
                    message: "Customer not found"
                });
                return;
            }
        });
    } else {
        reject({
            status: 404,
            message: "Customer not found"
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

the async function:

```
async function customerAccountLookUpRequest(customerLookUpData) {
    var accountLookUp = config.app.url;
    let data = await axios.get(accountLookUp).then(accountLookUpResult => {
        for (i = 0; i < accountLookUpResult.data.length; i++) {
            var requestaccount = accountLookUpResult.data[i].accountNumber;
            if (requestaccount == customerLookUpData.lookupAccount) {
                accountLookUpResult.data[i].customerId = customerLookUpData.customerId;
                accountLookUpResult.data[i].status = 1;
                return accountLookUpResult.data[i];
            }
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

I am new to node js and trying to understand the concept of async await. Please help.

Comment: If you are new to a topic, please read at least some introduction/tutorial, e.g. the [MDN for using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) along with [MDN for async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), or any good tutorial of your choosing. You appear to have no understanding at all, what async functions are for, and how they are supposed to behave.

Answer (score 0):

An async function waits for a Promise to return. The function that has the loop should be declared as async and the customerAccountLookUpRequest function should return a promise. Then use the await operator to call the function. Simple example:

```
class some_class {

    constructor() {
    }

    async my_loop() {
        let _self = this;
        for (let i = 0; i < customerlookupresponse.data.length; i++) {
            let data = await _self.customerAccountLookUpRequest(accountlookUpData);
            console.log("----" + i + " -- " + data);
        }
    }

    customerAccountLookUpRequest(customerLookUpData) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(accountLookUp).then(accountLookUpResult => {
                resolve(accountLookUpResult);
            });
        });
    }
}
```